# Eloquent relationship for multiple table

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.4

I am working in laravel5.4. I have created four table as **ticket**, **users**, and **company**. Here, I have stored **users** **id** in **ticket** table. And stored **company** **id** in **users** table.

Here, I want to show **ticket's** user name with that **users** company name.

Here, I have create relation for it that looks like below.

**Ticket model :**

```
public function requesters(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User','requester_id');
}
```

Here **requester_id** is who create **ticket**.

**Users model :**

```
public function company()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Admin\Company');
}
```

**Company model :**

```
public function Users()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Users');
}
```

Here, I have written query to get users information that looks like below.

```
Ticket::with('requesters')->orderBy('subject','asc')->paginate(10);
```

Now, I want to fetch company information or **request_id** So what changes should I have to do in this query to fetch company info along with ticket and users ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to to Eager load multiple relationship you can put them all in single `with` like this:

```
Ticket::with('requesters','requesters.company')->orderBy('subject','asc')->paginate(10);
```

but if you load nested relationship you can use shorter notation - you can omit parent relationship, so it's enough to use here:

```
Ticket::with('requesters.company')->orderBy('subject','asc')->paginate(10);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it should work for this case:

```
Ticket::with('requesters')
      ->with('requesters.company')
      ->orderBy('subject','asc')->paginate(10);
```